# How to insert add to cart link to icon - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I tried to replace the Add To Cart button by this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button' );
function replace_default_button(){
    return __( '<i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

and I insert the code bellow to my woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php

```
global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
$product->add_to_cart_text()
),
$product );
```

and the result I received is button Add to Cart replace to Shopping icon but without link, could anybody help me fix this ?!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can edit the template page, then why can't you replace add_to_cart_text with icon html

```
global $product;

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
    '<i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>'
    ),
    $product );
```